# Localization of a ring at a height $1$ prime ideal is a valuation ring?

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be the localization of a ring at a height $1$ prime ideal. Is it always a valuation ring, even if it is no discrete valuation ring?

Edit: Another related question: Let $X/k$ be a smooth variety and $x \in X$ a codimension $1$ point. Is $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ a DVR?

Comment: Valuation rings are integrally closed, but there is no reason to think that the local rings of dimension $1$ are so.

Comment: @user5262: yes to the edited question. See Hagen's answer.

Comment: -1 for editing your question one week later. The right thing would have been to post it as another question. (Of course, during this time you could have said thanks to those who bothered to answer you, but this is another story.)

Comment: @user26857 actually posting comments containing only thanks and nothing else is discouraged on the network.

Answer (score 4):

A concrete counterexample is the following: $R=K[X^2,X^3]$. Then $\dim R=1$ and $R$ is not integrally closed (why?). If all the localizations of $R$ are valuation rings, in particular integrally closed, then $R=\cap_{\mathfrak p\in\operatorname{Spec(R)-\{(0)\}}} R_{\mathfrak p}$ is integrally closed, a contradiction.

Comment: This is a good counter example.

Answer (score 3):

In general the answer is no.

The localization of a noetherian ring $R$ at a height-1-prime is a (discrete) valuation ring, if $R$ is normal.

H